# I can only see Tree View and not Screens View. Why is this so?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

All the videos I watch, show Tree View and Screens View options on the left side of a screen. For some reason, I can only see the Tree View and not the Screens View option. How can I see the Screens View option?

[image: my screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are watching last year videos - where the previous version of canvas app designer being used. There were two views - Tree view & Thumbnail view. Refer the below screenshot from [this blog](https://powersweet.blog/2018/08/05/learning-from-a-powerapp-created-from-data-part-2-powerapps-studio/):

[image]

App designer is rapidly evolving, so lot of options getting changed quicker. Sometimes options are getting removed as well, like the thumbnail view you are pointing out.

Comment: Good to know. there is no problem with my version of PowerApps .